# Java ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet и Clob

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

необходимо из `ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet` получить `clob` значение из oracle. Подскажите как это сделать? спасибо.

Comment: [что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо что-то типа такого:

```
ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet.getResultSet().getClob(columnIndex);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Comment: Спасибо на хлеб не намажешь :)